# How to filter the items without looping

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a better way to query so that i dont have to loop and append the users to a list because when the length of items is very large say 10000 then it has to query 10000 times. Is there a way to avoid it?

```
user_list = []
items = Items.objects.all()
for item in items:  
        userobjects = Users.objects.filter(item=item.id)
        user = userobjects[0].user
        user_list.append(user)
```

Comment: You say you know how to do it directly in the database; and my experience is that as long as you can express it in SQL, you can do it with django orm! And worst case, [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) is there for it; but if you know your SQL query and feel like typing it here might help getting an answer quicker.

Answer (score 1):

*Update*

As pointed out by Sandip Agarwal, if you only want the first one, there is not easy SQL AFAIK, for performance I would do it like

```
user_list = []
cur = None
# If there is customized ordering, 
# you could put the customization after 'item' in the following code
for user in Users.objects.filter(item__isnull=False).order_by('item').iterator():
    if cur != user.item_id:
        user_list.append(user)
        cur = user.item_id
```

---

You haven't provided any code of models `Item` and `User`, so simply guess here:

```
User.objects.filter(item__isnull=False)   
# or 
User.objects.filter(item__in=Items.objects.all())
```

Comment: I think magus wants the `first object` of `Users` referencing/having each object of `Items`.

Comment: Here, still we are `looping over` the list of `Users` if not `Items` which is still costly. Is it at all possible to get this done in a cheaper way?

Comment: @SandipAgarwal not for the requirement AFAIK. The requirement is a bit obscure, it does not show the relationship between the `User` and `Item`, which could be either a modeled FK or an `IntegerField`. Also, the ordering of the queryset `Users.objects.filter(item=item.id)` is important to the result. I am just feeling that the OP might only want some normal ORM operation but express it to lead us to another direction.

Comment: Supposedly, if it is a FK, how would this solution change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MYSQL join to join tables and get the expected result without iterrating.

Comment: yes, i know how to do it using sql queries. wanted to know if there is a way to do it in django

Comment: Just check the docs...you will get it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
user_list = User.objects.filter(users__items__in=Items.objects.all())
```

However, since you're not filtering the items, you're really just looking for `Users` that have any `Item`, so you can actually do:

```
user_list = User.objects.filter(users__items__isnull=False)
```

Comment: In your solution as well, its not selecting the `first object` of `Users` referencing/having each object of `Items`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by getting all Item id's then using that to filter the User's with an IN clause (in the list), with a distinct filter on the returned users. I can't test directly at the moment, but something like the following should do this for you:

```
item_ids = Item.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True) # Get a list of Item id's values, since you don't need the whole Item object

user_list = User.objects.filter(items__id__in=item_ids).distinct('id') #Distinct on user id/username, filtered on those users matching an item id

user_list = list( user_list ) # Convert to a list
```

Note: You can use `Item.objects.all()` directly instead of the values_list. This may result in a bigger/slower query, try profiling it.

If this doesn't resolve the question you might need to add a clearer description of exactly what you want to see in an output. You're doing a select and taking the first value that comes out (*usually* this will be the first one in the database). You may be able to emulate that with the above by sorting before distinct:

```
user_list = User.objects.filter(items__id__in=item_ids).order_by('id').distinct('id')
```

If this is something you are going to do a lot, a faster solution may be to add another field to the Item record called first_user, that is set when the first user is added via the save hook.